# DNS not automatically retrieved

Tags: dns

So, I switch the IPv4 method to manual and leave DNS on automatic. After tying in the static IP I want, the subnet mask, the default gateway and then turning WiFi off and on to reconnect. You would assume there would be no problems, but surprise surprise, it hasn't retrieved the DNS addresses from the router like it does in the "DCHP" method. Why doesn't it retrieve the DNS addresses in the "Manual" method when the DNS "Automatic" switch is flipped on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is surely a bug since the only way to automatically assign DNS servers is via DHCP.

- When using static IP addressing (manual) you must enter the DNS server(s) manually.
- When using dynamic IP addressing (DHCP) you will get the DNS server(s) assigned to you automatically. But you can override the automatic DNS assignment from DHCP by entering one or more static DNS servers to use.

Comment: I was actually talking about the reverse, since it still has the Automatic switch for the DNS on On when the method is Manual, but it acts as if the switch isn't there. It's in the same row as the label DNS.

Comment: Well that was my point, it must be a bug since you should not be able to have Automatic DNS when the method is Manual. The switch should be grayed out when you are using Manual IP address assignment.